# can we prevent office 365 group owners from having full control permission on the related SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365, administration, office-365-groups

When creating modern team site, the office 365 group owners will be defined as site collection admins and as site owners.

Now we can remove them from been site collection admins, but inside the SharePoint owner group seems they will be hidden inside the list view and when we chose to show them we can not remove them, as follow:-

[image]

[image]

so is there any way to remove the office 365 owners from having full control permission on the SharePoint site?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you're attempting to do is not supported (you can confirm this by contacting Microsoft support).

I personally would avoid changing those default settings on group connected sites (such as owners being given site collection administrator permission), since it's not clear if that's supported or what adverse affects it could have,

You can of course create a team site without a connected Microsoft 365 group, which would give you full control over SharePoint groups and any AD groups you wish to use with the site.

Answer (score 0):

By default, site owners are site collection administrators, so they should have the Full Control permission level. If you don't want to have Full Control, why not remove users from the site owner.